# Como obter o número de linhas de uma StringList e aplicar?

Tags: java, string, loop

Eu tenho uma `StringList` dentro de um arquivo `mensagens.txt`, eu gostaria de contar quantas linhas tem essa `StringList` contida dentro desse arquivo. Para cada linha da *string* 1 código sera executado dentro código do *plugin*.

Se a `StringList` tiver 10 linhas o código ira executar:

```
web.setScore(1) para a linha 1
web.setScore(2) para a linha 2.....
web.setScore(10) para a linha 10
```

O código que eu criei é esse:

```
public class ScoreBoard implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public void pj(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
        for (String list : Main.getMensagens().getStringList("Scoreboard")) {;

        Scoreboard scoreboard = Bukkit.getServer().getScoreboardManager().getNewScoreboard();
        Objective obj = scoreboard.registerNewObjective(Main.getMensagens().getString("Titulo"), "dummy");
        obj.setDisplaySlot(DisplaySlot.SIDEBAR);
          Score web = obj.getScore(list);
          web.setScore(1);

        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        p.setScoreboard(scoreboard);
    }
  }
}
```

O meu problema é com o `web.setScore`, eu preciso que ele pegue o número de linhas `StringList` e execute automaticamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transforme em um `for` e passe ter controle sobre o índice.

```
public class ScoreBoard implements Listener {
    @EventHandler
    public void pj(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
        /*tipo de retorno do getStringList*/ list = Main.getMensagens().getStringList("Scoreboard");
        for (int i = 0;  i < list.length; i++) {    
             Scoreboard scoreboard = Bukkit.getServer().getScoreboardManager().getNewScoreboard();
             Objective obj = scoreboard.registerNewObjective(Main.getMensagens().getString("Titulo"), "dummy");
             obj.setDisplaySlot(DisplaySlot.SIDEBAR);
             Score web = obj.getScore(list.get(i));
             web.setScore(i);
             Player p = e.getPlayer();
             p.setScoreboard(scoreboard);
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/StringList.java).